# search Undefined variable in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to write a search function but I got the error when I click the search button (Undefined variable: requests)..

this is my form

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <form action="/member_search" methode="get">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input type="search"  name="searchinput" class="form-control">
                <span class="input-group-prepend">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">search</button>
              </div>
            </form>
           </div>

            <div class="card-body">
              <table class="table">

                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">status</th>
                    <th scope="col">type</th>
                    <th scope="col">date</th>
                    <th scope="col"> request number</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach ($requests as $request)
                    <tr>
                    <th scope="col">{{$request->status->name}}</th>
                    <th scope="col">{{$request->type->name}}</th>
                    <th scope="row">{{$request->created_at}}</th>
                    <th scope="row">{{$request->uniid}}</th>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
                </tbody>
               </table>
               </div>
             </div>
            </div>
         </div>
       </div>
```

and this is my function in my controller and I got the error Undefined variable: requests with this function

```
  public function searchmember(Request $request)
{
$searchinput= $request->get('searchinput');
$posts= DB::table('students')->where ( 'uniid', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchinput . '%' )->paginate(1);
return view('Committee.Request.index', ['posts' => $posts]);

}
```

and I this is my route I try to do it as (get) but it does not work

```
Route::any('/member_search','RequestController@searchmember');
```

Comment: you have 2 return statement, the function will stop at the first return, the second return can't be reached.

Comment: What is `$requests` supposed to be? Shouldn't you be looping `$posts` instead?

Comment: I delete the second return .. where are you mean should I use  $posts?

Comment: Did you check this?

Answer (score 3):

You should use the variable in the loop which variable is passing to view:

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">{{$post->status->name}}</th>
        <th scope="col">{{$post->type->name}}</th>
        <th scope="row">{{$post->created_at}}</th>
        <th scope="row">{{$post->uniid}}</th>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I chsnge the function instead of the form  `public function searchmember()
    {
    $search = Input::get ( 'search' );
    $requests= DB::table('sickleaves')->where ( 'uniid', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%' )->paginate(1);
    return view('Committee.Request.index', ['requests' => $requests]);`   and the error now is Undefined property: stdClass::$status

Comment: Okay, you want to use`$requests` fine. then inside your loop would you please try `<th scope="col">{{$request->status[0]->name}}</th>`

Comment: If I write  {{$request->status[0]->name}} show the error Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Comment: Hmm, Okay then write like this - `{{$request->status[0]->name or ''}}`

Comment: Error Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Comment: this is because of in your relation there has no for every status relation `name` data, some are missing. That's why you are getting this error. Would you please try -`{{$request->status[0]->name ?? ''}}`

Comment: I did it as you said .. but the result of search not shown the status and type?

Comment: Now your first line problem is solved. do same for second line. your second line is about `type`. I hope I catch the reason

Comment: okay,, work fine now but the col status and type not show! why?

Comment: I think it should be better approach - `{{ !empty($request->status) ? $request->status->name:'' }}`

Comment: status and type I use the ( data base seed) .. is this reason or not?

Comment: If `posts` primary key `id` does not belong to `status` in which you used `post_id` foreign key, then you will get empty as far we discussed. Would you please check one, post `id` does belong to `status`.